# Error during MySQL installation - Database initialization failed

Tags: mysql

During the final step of the installation of MySQLServer (Apply Configurations), I get a strange error. I can't get it. Here's the Log :

```
Beginning configuration step: Initializing database (may take a long time)

Attempting to run MySQL Server with --initialize-insecure option...
Starting process for MySQL Server 8.0.31...
Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --console --initialize-insecure=on --lower-case-table-names=1...
'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.31) initializing of server in progress as process 13960
mysqld: File '.\??bin.index' not found (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
The designated data directory C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
Aborting
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
Process for mysqld, with ID 13960, was run successfully and exited with code 1.
Failed to start process for MySQL Server 8.0.31.
Database initialization failed.
Ended configuration step: Initializing database (may take a long time)
` ` ` 
What's wrong here? Please help me
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: screenshot]
you need to tick Show Advanced and Logging options, and after that you will be able to change the filename of your log-in Logging Options (all of them have to be in English).